# segmentation fault in a simple command line program

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a simple program that calls cat with system() on a file location entered as a command argument. But I am getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) each time I call the file. Could you please check why (I cannot see anywhere in my program I am doing something with memory to get this error!).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s filename", argv[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("commad: %s", strcat("cat ", argv[1]));
        system(strcat("cat ", argv[1]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to modify a string literal.

Comment: could you please explain

Comment: @MohamedAliJamaoui you need to provide a destination buffer for strcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify string literals, such as `"cat "` they are usually stored in a read only segment in memory when your executable is loaded, and when you try to modify it, you will get the segmentation fault that you asked to explain about.

Consider using `std::string` instead, it is the more idiomatic C++ way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s filename", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::string command("cat ");
        command += argv[1];
        printf("command: %s", command.c_str());
        return system(command.c_str());
    }
}
```

The `std::string` object will allocate memory dynamically as necessary to accommodate the additional characters you add to it. However, if you wish to continue with C-strings, you will need to manage the character buffer explicitly:

```
char *buffer = static_cast<char*>(malloc(5 + strlen(argv[1])));
strcpy(buffer, "cat ");
strcat(buffer, argv[1]);
printf("command: %s", buffer);
// ...
free(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `strcat` calls you try to modify string literal "cat " which is undefined behaviour. The first argument of strcat should be a buffer where you can write, not the string literal.

Answer (score 2):

You are using strcat incorrectly. You need to provide a destination buffer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if(argc == 2) {
             char[20] c = "cat";
             strcat(c, argv[1]);
             printf("commad: %s", c);
             system(c);
        }
        else {
            printf("usage: %s filename", argv[0]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

OR don't concatenate

```
printf("commad: %s%s", "cat ", argv[1]);
```